# Why color changes after redrawing again on canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

Here a sample of code that product the effect on color.

The question is "why rectangles (rect 1 and rect 2) are not the same color ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 25, 15); //rect 1

    ctx.strokeRect(55, 5, 25, 15); // rect 2
    ctx.strokeRect(55, 5, 25, 15); // rect 2 again
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe because `5 != 55` ....

Comment: void ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the line width. If you change it to 2, you get the same rectangles, but without the opacity.

```
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 24, 14); //rect 1
ctx.strokeRect(55, 5, 24, 14); // rect 2
ctx.strokeRect(55, 5, 24, 14); // rect 2 again
```

I assume that for some reason, the browser uses a stroke that is below 1 pixel at the point on the line and to compensate for that, it reduces the opacity of the stroke.

Example with line width of 2:
https://jsfiddle.net/2buo5cfw/4/

Comment: This is right, even if you don't understand why. Basically, the line is at the exact position of `55,5`, so it draws along that line, which means half of the line is on the `54` side, and half is on the `55` side. This results in an antialiased result of a partially-transparent line. Drawing it again increases the opacity. Drawing it with a width of `2` will fully cover both the `54` and `55` pixels. Drawing it at `55.5, 5.5` will produce the intended rectangle in the first place.

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2buo5cfw/6/) with the rectangle at the "half-pixel" coordinate. Notice the crisp one-pixel-wide line.

Answer (score 1):

because you are drawing two rectangles in the same place and that make the color of canvas that way.

Test this one.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 25, 15); //rect 1

ctx.strokeRect(55, 5, 25, 15); // rect 2
ctx.strokeRect(75, 5, 25, 15); // rect 2 again
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```